# resize images in python

Tags: image, resize, python-2.5

Can i resize images in python to given height and width,i use python 2.5, and i tried as this tutorial http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm, and i installed PIL library for images,but when i try to write:

```
import Image
im = Image.open("test.jpg")
```

i got undefined variable from import:open
although `import Image`doesn't give errors?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your import appears to be the problem. Use this instead of "import Image":

```
from PIL import Image
```

Then go on like so:

```
image = Image.open('/example/path/to/image/file.jpg/')
image.thumbnail((80, 80), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save('/some/path/thumb.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=88)
```

Comment: I'm very surprised by this, given that even over at the PIL website, [even the tutorials](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm) show that using just `import Image` should work. Is this a newer PIL version thing? I've used PIL for over a year and have only ever imported it with `import Image` and have never had a problem...

Comment: @EMS:the problem may be in the version of python,which ver you use?i use 2.5 ver.

Comment: I'm using 2.6 and 2.7. I don't think it's the Python version, unless you're using an older version of PIL. What is your PIL version, mine is 1.1.7.

Comment: Strange indeed. Possibly it depends on the way PIL has been installed. In my case, I need this type of import.

Comment: Using Python 2.7 with PIL 1.1.7

Comment: If you are using a Linux system, it might be as simple as making sure that the PIL .so file appears in the right distutils folder. This might be taken care of automatically with the Linux install script, but perhaps not on other platforms.

Comment: @EMS:i installed the latest version these day,but when i tried to resize image using the above tutorial as: 'out = im.resize((128, 128))'the resize method is undefined??

Comment: @Nasmoni: used windows OS and intalled Python Imaging Library 1.1.7 for Python 2.5

Comment: Yeah, PIL has always been a headache to deal with for me. I try to use only the [Mahotas](http://luispedro.org/software/mahotas) library combined with [scikits.image](http://scikits-image.org/) to avoid the need for "special" type images, like what PIL and OpenCV require you to use. I want my images to always just be NumPy arrays and not fool with it.

Comment: @Nasmon:when i tried to write **image.thumbnail((80, 80), Image.ANTIALIAS)** i get that thumbnail is undefined variable from import??

Answer (score 3):

To whom it may be of use: Just found that on the [official Pillow website](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/installation.html). You probably used Pillow and not PIL.

> Warning
>
> Pillow >= 1.0 no longer supports “import Image”. Please use “from PIL
>   import Image” instead.

Answer (score 1):

This script resizes all images in a given folder:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
path = "path"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
def resize():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            img = Image.open(path+item)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            img = img.resize((width,hight ), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img.save(f + '.jpg') 
resize()
```

Answer (score 1):

- **you can resize image using `skimage`**

  ```py
  from skimage.transform import resize
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  img=plt.imread('Sunflowers.jpg')
  image_resized =resize(img, (244, 244))
  ```
- **plotting resized image**

  ```py
  plt.subplot(1,2,1)
  plt.imshow(img)
  plt.title('original image')

  plt.subplot(1,2,2)
  plt.imshow(image_resized)
  plt.title('image_resized')
  ```

- **for further code illustration : [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_rescale.html)**

Comment: This does not really answer the question. It proposes another method.
It could be useful, yes, but is not a direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from PIL import Image

imagePath = os.getcwd() + 'childFolder/myImage.png'
newPath = os.getcwd() + 'childFolder/newImage.png'
cropSize = 150, 150

img = Image.open(imagePath)
img.thumbnail(cropSize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save(newPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have troubles with PIL the other alternative could be scipy.misc library. Assume that you want to resize to size 48x48 and your image located in same directory as script

```
from from scipy.misc import imread
from scipy.misc import imresize
```

and then:

```
img = imread('./image_that_i_want_to_resize.jpg')
img_resized = imresize(img, [48, 48])
```

Comment: Note that on scipy.org it says _imread is deprecated! imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use imageio.imread instead._